# Displaying a custom attribute of a div with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a hobby coder and have a query that I just cant seem to find an answer for. I would think that it would be quite simple, but perhaps I'm not searching the correct syntax... hopefully you can help me.

I have a series of `<div>`s on a page with a number of custom attributes. Here is the example:

```
<div class="face" rownumber="1" rowposition="0" playername="Jo Smith" playerrole="Captain" 
     playerposition="0" style="position: absolute; left: 772.632px; top: 215.934px; 
     width: 46.5668px; height: 46.5789px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></div>
```

How in css, can I have all the `<div>`s with the class of 'face' display the "rownumber".... and then after clicking on a button, they all display "playername".... and then after clicking on a different button, they all display "playerrole"

Thankyou for reading and hopefully answering....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This works by changing the class on the 'selected' element, and using CSS to render the different values based on what class it is.

```js
$('.selector').click(function(){
  $('#selected').attr('class',$(this).text());
});
```

```css
.rownumber .face:after { content: attr(rownumber); }
.playername .face:after { content: attr(playername); }
.playerrole .face:after { content: attr(playerrole); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='selected' class='rownumber'>
<div class="face" rownumber="1" rowposition="0" playername="Jo Smith" playerrole="Captain" 
     playerposition="0" style="position: absolute; left: 772.632px; top: 215.934px; 
     width: 46.5668px; height: 46.5789px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></div>
 </div>
<button class='selector'>rownumber</button>
<button class='selector'>playername</button>
<button class='selector'>playerrole</button>
```

If you want an all css solution, you can do this:

```css
[name=selected][value=rownumber]:checked ~ div .face:after {
  content: attr(rownumber);
}
[name=selected][value=playername]:checked ~ div .face:after {
  content: attr(playername);
}
[name=selected][value=playerrole]:checked ~ div .face:after {
  content: attr(playerrole);
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='selected' value='rownumber'>Rownumber
<input type='radio' name='selected' value='playername'>Playername
<input type='radio' name='selected' value='playerrole'>Playerrole
<div>
  <div class="face" rownumber="1" rowposition="0" playername="Jo Smith" playerrole="Captain" playerposition="0" style="position: absolute; left: 772.632px; top: 215.934px; 
     width: 46.5668px; height: 46.5789px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the submissions. Learnt alot from each of you. You are all awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and `.attr( attributeName)` function to get the value of attribute, and after again use jQuery to add that text (value of attribute) where it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".face").each(function(){
    var rowNumber = $(this).attr('rownumber');
    $(this).text(rowNumber);
  });
});

$("#pn").click(function(){
  $(".face").each(function(){
    var playerName = $(this).attr('playername');
    $(this).text(playerName);
  });
});

$("#pr").click(function(){
  $(".face").each(function(){
    var playerRole = $(this).attr('playerrole');
    $(this).text(playerRole);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="face" rownumber="1" rowposition="0" playername="Jo Smith" playerrole="Captain" playerposition="0"></div>

<div class="face" rownumber="2" rowposition="0" playername="Rob krest" playerrole="Pirate" playerposition="0"></div>

<div class="face" rownumber="3" rowposition="0" playername="Alex Konst" playerrole="Cyborg" playerposition="0"></div>

<button id="pn">Show player Name</button>
<button id="pr">Show player Role</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you work with `data-` attributes.

Here an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/z424eyq0/3/

I added some buttons which paste the content of the different div `data-` attribute into the node itself.

```
<div class="face" data-rownumber="1" data-rowposition="0" data-playername="Jo Smith" data-playerrole="Captain" data-playerposition="0" style=" width: 46.5668px; height: 46.5789px; color:  #000; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Test1</div>
<div class="face" data-rownumber="2" data-rowposition="0" data-playername="Mc Fitti" data-playerrole="Captain" data-playerposition="0" style="width: 46.5668px; height: 46.5789px; color: #000; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Test2</div>
<button class="js-number">Show Number</button>
<button class="js-name">Show Name</button>
```

And some js:

```
$('.js-number').click(function() {  
   $('.face').each(function() {  
      $(this).text($(this).data('rownumber'));   
   }); 
 })

$('.js-name').click(function() {    
   $('.face').each(function() {  
     $(this).text($(this).data('playername'));   
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vanilla JS:

Similarly to Rodrigo I'm using `data-` attributes:

```
<div
  class="face"
  data-rownumber="1"
  data-rowposition="0"
  data-playername="Jo Smith"
  data-playerrole="Captain"
  data-playerposition="0"
></div>

<button data-type="rownumber">Row</button>
<button data-type="playername">Name</button>
<button data-type="playerrole">Role</button>
```

Grab the buttons, and all the cards

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var face = document.querySelectorAll('.face');
```

Loop over the buttons and add event listeners to them:

```
[].slice.call(buttons).forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', show.bind(this, button.dataset.type), false);
});
```

The function loops over the elements in the `face` collection and assigns the `type` passed into the function as `argument[0]` to its `textContent`.

```
function show() {
  for (var i = 0; i < face.length; i++) {
    face[i].textContent = face[i].dataset[arguments[0]];
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zk6gxotd/12/)